# Can Laravel hasOne be used with belongsToMany?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have two tables:

`Users: id, name, country_id`

`Countries: id, name`

Of course each `user` can only have one `country`, but each `country` is assigned to multiple `users`.

So would it be safe to have a `User` model that utilizes `hasOne` and a `Country` model that uses `belongsToMany` method?

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) makes it seem like you can't mix and match different types of relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is actually a [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many) relationship, where one country has many users. Your `Country` model should utilize a `hasMany` relationship, while your user would have a `belongsTo` relationship.

Comment: Ahh ok.  Was confused about it cause it seems like the relationship is reversed than what it shows in the docs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@Andy has already answered well.
Anyway, my advice is to always think in the following way to create a [One-To-One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), [One-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), or a [Many-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

- In the table **with the foreign key** (if any) use `belongsTo`
- In the other table **without the foreign key** use `hasOne` or `hasMany`
- In **any of them have a foreign key**, you have a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship and you must use `belongsToMany` in both of them (you need the pivot table, of course).

Comment: Nice thank you.  Much easier to visualize data that way.