# Laravel One To Many Relationship Role to preserve

Tags: laravel

I have a relationship where Order hasOne ( belongsTo ) Location , where the location could have Many ( belongs to many Orders ) ..

which method should i use for each eloquent model ..
Which Model should has the (Has) method , and which should has (Belongs) method , depends on what , i can read it in both ways ..

I need a general Role .. when i could read the relationship in two ways like ..
the order hasOne Location , So location belongsToMany orders .
and ..
the order belongsto  Location , So location hasMany orders .

what is the role here ??

this is the tables i have ..

`````
Location table..

        Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('manager_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('city');
            $table->float('latitude')->nullable();
            $table->float('longitude')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
````

and Orders Table

````
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('trade');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->enum('priority',['Regular-72h','Important-48h','Urgent-24h','Crisis-psh']);
            $table->text('notes')->nullable();
            $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamp('entry');
            $table->timestamp('exit');
            $table->integer('close_key')->unsigned();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
`````

I searched here but the same point i asked about did not find to be clear .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Location {
...
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}


class Order {
...
    public function location() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
    }
}
```

Think of it this way:

Your Location can have many orders(hasMany) and one order belongs to a location(belongsTo).

More general explanation you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598711/4996445).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in the laracasts From @Snapey

[Answer at The Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/order-and-location-one-to-many-relationship)

the error was in the location_id column .